To indicate UI components are not yet usable, is the "wait" ⌛ or "not-allowed"  cursor better?
This answer makes the argument that simpler is clearer and thus is better, and the "not-allowed" CSS cursor  is more direct (in my opinion) than the "wait" cursor ⌛. Another answer to the same question suggests using the "not-allowed" cursor to indicate the UI cannot be interacted with.
However, the "not-allowed" cursor is a bit "louder" and thus more obtrusive.
This answer only considers "wait" vs "progress"   , but it and the MDN description of the "wait" cursor makes the case for "wait" to be used to indicate interaction cannot happen.
The specific case I'm interested in concerns server-side rendered UI buttons, Login and Register. When the user first arrives on the page, the buttons which are in the site nav header are visible to the user for a short time before they are hydrated (that is, before clicking them will cause anything to happen).
Here is a Codepen demonstrating the two options: https://codepen.io/stan-stan/pen/dyBWYrv
And a gif:


My first reaction would be that if you want this to be a modern application, used and understood by a broad audience on different platforms, then step away from the cursor idea. Seeing that hourglass on MacOS is weird for example and on mobile there is no indicator at all. Use a disabled button state and show a loading icon on or near the buttons themselves would be my advice. But maybe you can explain why you want to use this cursor concept? As for now it raises a lot of questions.

@jazZRo That's very helpful input. A loading indicator overlaid on the buttons ultimately might be more appropriate. For most users, it's a pretty short window of time (like 300ms or something) where the buttons are unusable, but visible. I do wonder if a loading indicator might be more distracting than helpful if it pops in and out in such a short time. But your observation concerning mobile users is insightful!

You want to be clear in distinguishing what the system is not ready to do, vs. what the user is not allowed to do.
The ⏳ (Hourglass) cursor suggest that the system is not yet available to interact. This is more appropriate for your use case.
The  (Forbidden) cursor suggests that the user does not have the permissions to interact.
What you have in the gif is clear. One extra thing you could do is to have a disabled state for the not-allowed.
A common pattern for the 'not-allowed' cursor is a tooltip on the disabled element, often with a message similar to:
You do not have the necessary permissions to {action}

In my opinion, only the wait cursor makes sense, since your UI is literally loading.
Not-allowed is meant for disabled states of existing elements.
But again, why do you even need this?
Are your users clicking on buttons in less than 300ms, before the script is loaded?
First of all, you might be overengineering this.
Second, most users will not notice or understand the change of cursor.
Third, if you are concerned about users with slow wifi, maybe you should add a clear loading indicator for the whole page, not just the buttons.
Nonetheless, you could try a CSS animation with opacity from 0 to 1, to indicate that the buttons are becoming interactable.
